# File Not Read Properly

Tags: java, file, output

I'm having trouble reading from a file. I get the data from the file but when I go to display them the output looks more and more off. Here is my code. I don't want a line of numbers. I just want them all straight down like the first line of numbers was processed. I thought the `printf` would help but it didn't.

```
File f = new File("divers.dat");
Scanner kb = new Scanner(f);

while (kb.hasNext()) {
            
            String name = kb.nextLine();
            String school = kb.nextLine();
            String s1 = kb.next();
            String s2 = kb.next();
            String s3 = kb.next();
            String s4 = kb.next();
            String s5 = kb.next();
            String s6 = kb.next();
            String s7 = kb.next();
            String diff = kb.next();
            
            System.out.printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s", name, school, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, diff);
}
```

**Here is my file format:**

```
Lucieta Spinelli
Bryn Mawr College
8 9 8 7 8 8 8 2.5
7 8 7 6 7 7 6 3.7
8 7 6 7 7 6 8 3.2
LiPing Sun
Rutgers University
6.5 5 9.5 7.5 8 8.5 7 2.3
7 9 7.5 9 8.5 6.5 8 2.6
6 4 5 9 7 8 6 3.0
Greg McEntire
University of Southern California
9 8 8.5 9.5 9 9.5 7 2.3
9 7 8 8 7.5 8.5 7.5 2.6
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 3.4
Shiva Vadaparthy
Northwestern University
9 8 9.5 9.5 7.5 8 8.5 3.0
8 9 8.5 7.5 9 8.5 8 3.6
7.5 9 8 7 8.5 8 7 4.1
Elizabeth Bennet
Oxford University
7 8 9 8 7 7 8 2.4
8 8 6 7 9 7 8 2.7
8 7 8 6 9 8 9 3.0
Sofia Berrios
Universidad Simon Bolivar
8.5 7.5 9.5 9 7 8.5 8 2.4
8 7 8 9 8 6 7 3.0
7 5.5 6.5 7 5 6.5 7 3.6
Amir Majid
Reed College
4 5 6 5 3 5 7 2.8
7 6 7 8 7 9 8 2.9
8 9 7 9 8.5 8 9 3.4
James Pajuio
University of Pennsylvania
8 7 8 9 8 6 7 2.8
7.5 9 8 7 8.5 8 7 3.0
7.5 9 8 7 8.5 8 7 4.3
Sharon Lewis
Howard University
8 9 9.5 9 8.5 8 9 2.7
4 5 5.5 7 6.5 4.5 5 3.2
8 7 8 9 8 8 7 4.0
Divya Patel
Temple University
7 9 7.5 9 8.5 6.5 8 2.1
8 7 8 6 9 8 9 2.3
3.5 5.5 4 5 3 4 4.5 4.3
Guo Zhang
Portland State University
5 6 5.5 7 6.5 7 5.5 6 3.0
8 7 8.5 9 7.5 8.5 8 3.2
9 8 9.5 8.5 9 8.5 9.5 4.1
Tomasz Wojaczyk
Tufts University
8 8 7 8 7 8 7 2.6
5 4 5 6 7 5 5 2.9
8 6 6 7 8 7 6 3.6
```

**Here is the output:**

```
Lucieta Spinelli
Bryn Mawr College
8
9
8
7
8
8
8
2.5
7 8 7 6 7 7 6 3.7
8
7
6
7
7
6
8
3.2
LiPing Sun
Rutgers
University
6.5
5
9.5
7.5
8
8.5 7 2.3
7 9 7.5 9 8.5 6.5 8 2.6
6
4
5
9
7
8
6
3.0
Greg McEntire
University
of
Southern
California
9
8
8.5
9.5 9 9.5 7 2.3
9 7 8 8 7.5 8.5 7.5 2.6
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
3.4
Shiva Vadaparthy
Northwestern
University
9
8
9.5
9.5
7.5
8 8.5 3.0
8 9 8.5 7.5 9 8.5 8 3.6
7.5
9
8
7
8.5
8
7
4.1
Elizabeth Bennet
Oxford
University
7
8
9
8
7
7 8 2.4
8 8 6 7 9 7 8 2.7
8
7
8
6
9
8
9
3.0
Sofia Berrios
Universidad
Simon
Bolivar
8.5
7.5
9.5
9
7 8.5 8 2.4
8 7 8 9 8 6 7 3.0
7
5.5
6.5
7
5
6.5
7
3.6
Amir Majid
Reed
College
4
5
6
5
3
5 7 2.8
7 6 7 8 7 9 8 2.9
8
9
7
9
8.5
8
9
3.4
James Pajuio
University
of
Pennsylvania
8
7
8
9
8 6 7 2.8
7.5 9 8 7 8.5 8 7 3.0
7.5
9
8
7
8.5
8
7
4.3
Sharon Lewis
Howard
University
8
9
9.5
9
8.5
8 9 2.7
4 5 5.5 7 6.5 4.5 5 3.2
8
7
8
9
8
8
7
4.0
Divya Patel
Temple
University
7
9
7.5
9
8.5
6.5 8 2.1
8 7 8 6 9 8 9 2.3
3.5
5.5
4
5
3
4
4.5
4.3
Guo Zhang
Portland
State
University
5
6
5.5
7
6.5 7 5.5 6 3.0
8 7 8.5 9 7.5 8.5 8 3.2
9
8
9.5
8.5
9
8.5
9.5
4.1
Tomasz Wojaczyk
Tufts
University
8
8
7
8
7
8 7 2.6
5 4 5 6 7 5 5 2.9
8
6
6
7
8
7
6
3.6
```

Comment: It is not clear what output you actually want. Do you want the [student] name on a single line? Do you want the name of the school on a single line? Do you want each number on a separate line? Maybe you could [edit] your question and post how you want the output to appear. You don't need to post the entire output, just enough to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to take out all new line elements `\n` from your print statement:

`System.out.printf("%s" + " " +"%s" + " " +"%s" + " " +"%s" + " " +"%s" + " " +"%s" + " " +"%s" + " " +"%s" + " " +"%s" + " " +"%s" + " " +", name, school, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, diff);`

Answer (score 0):

In every iteration, your code reads two full-line elements plus eight numbers, but your file has 24 numbers per block.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), [Scanner::next](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) *finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.* While [Scanner::nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) *advances this scanner past the **current line and returns the input that was skipped**.*

In your case, input is *repetition* of 2 lines of Strings (name and school) and 3 lines of numbers (8 numbers in each line). You have opted to read 2 lines of Strings (name and school) using `nextLine` and all numbers using `next`. Below are the problems in the sample code shared by you which we will fix:

1. In each iteration, after reading name and school, you need to read 24 numbers and not just 8 numbers.
2. Since you are using mix of `nextLine` (consumes new-line `\n`) and `next` (doesn't consume new-line `\n`), you need to be careful and consume all new-lines `\n` properly.
   E.g. After reading 8 numbers, you are still left to read a new-line `\n`. This new-line will be consumed upon the next call of `nextLine` (which *advances the scanner past the **current line and returns the input that was skipped**.*). If `nextLine` is not called after 8 numbers are read, scanner will not consume the new-line `\n` after those 8 numbers in input. And when you try to read name in the next iteration by calling `nextLine`, it will consume previous new-line instead of the line containing next name as per your expectations.
3. `\n` is missing at the last of `printf` so that the name in the next iteration is printed on the new-line.

With the fixes of all 3 points above, your code should look like:

```java
File f = new File("divers.dat");
Scanner kb = new Scanner(f);

while (kb.hasNext()) {
    
    String name = kb.nextLine();
    String school = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("%s\n%s\n", name, school);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // fix for point#1, read 24 numbers, not just 8
        String s1 = kb.next();
        String s2 = kb.next();
        String s3 = kb.next();
        String s4 = kb.next();
        String s5 = kb.next();
        String s6 = kb.next();
        String s7 = kb.next();
        String diff = kb.next();
        kb.nextLine(); // fix for point#2

        System.out.printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, diff);
        // fix for point#3 -------------------------------^

        // use this if all numbers are not required on new line, however
        // I would suggest to use nextLine() similar to name and school
        // instead of multiple next calls
        // System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, diff);
    }
}
```

**References:**

- [Working code with sample input/output](https://ideone.com/nN7zyq)
- [Difference between next() and nextLine() methods in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-in-java/)